# How to pass data around?

Tags: variables

I have different menu items. When the user clicks on a menu item, I want them to go to a particular destination. Each menu's destination has a different background color.

I'm thinking that I can pass a variable around and based on the value, I can set the bgcolor.
This is just one example of why I want to pass data around.

Does Wordpress have anything built in that allows me to do this? Should I use session variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have different menu items. When the user clicks on a menu item, I want them to go to a particular destination. Each menu's destination has a different background color.

When you say destination I assume you mean page or post.  If you use WordPress's built in body class and post class you can target the page or post in your CSS and assign a different background color for each.

**How to use WordPress body class:**

In header.php add body_class() between the body tags and WordPress will assign a different class to each page.  The body tag:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

This will output your body tag in html like so:

```
<body class="page page-id-11 page-template page-template-default">
```

To assign the background color in css:

```
body.page-id-11 {
background:#000000;
}
```

Then you would just repeat the above for each page that needs a different background color.

**How to use WordPress post class:**

In your template file that is displaying the post, single.php or index.php add the following in the loop:

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

This will output your html like so:

```
<div id="post-47" class="post-47 post type-post hentry category-your-category tag-your-tags">
```

Use CSS to target the post just like we did the body using any of the outputted class or ids

Comment: Thanks Chris_O.  That's a great answer and also allows me to do other visual customizations!

Answer (score 1):

WordPress doesn't use session variables ... so you might run into problems if you try that approach.  From your description, though, I'd suggest adding a variable via the URL's query string.  You can use WordPress permalinks system to do this, or merely add "?bg=123" to the end of the URL.  Then use that variable to determine which background color to use.